# Button with background and scale on click - Android

Tags: android, xml

I've a particular button to make. I need to define this button in xml, it's composed by two part: the icon or text and a monocolor background with setted alpha(only on background). The icon should be in the middle(with some adjustments) of the background. When I press the button it should scale(icon an background together) and back to original size on relase.

I've looked for some solution and found a selector, but it replace image with another one. There is a simply way to do this without replace image?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would be to go with selector. In one selector you would create a button with original size and in second selector you would create a button with smaller size, or whatever size you need.

Now for achieving the effect for icon and background together, you can set for button icon like this `android:drawable="@drawable/icon.png"` and for setting a background `android:background="@drawable/background.png"`.